# "Copy files from source folder to another location" in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, code-editor

In NetBeans IDE, for any project, I have an option to check "Copy files from source folder to another location", which copies files from my working directory to another directory every time I make any change in my working copy. I use this feature, because I have the other directory synced with Google Drive, which updates the testing server immediately when I make any changes.

Now I am trying to switch to PhpStorm from NetBeans, but I cannot find any such option in PhpStorm. Can anyone help me, how can achieve the same in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using Deployment functionality.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`
2. Create new entry of `Local or Shared Folder` type
3. Configure it (all tabs)
4. Mark it as Default for this project
5. Enable automatic deployment in `Deployment | Options` (look for `Upload changed files automatically` setting) .. or just use `Upload` or `Synchronize with...` actions manually

More in these [official manuals](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm) (with video and pictures).

Comment: Thanks for the step by step instruction and link of official manual. The video is 1 hour long, so I need to manage time later to watch it. For now, I followed your instructions and have setup the local folder entry and I found one option for "Upload changed files automatically to default server", which has options "Never", "Always", "On Explicit Save Action". I tried choosing "Always" and "On Explicit Save Action". For some reason, none of this works for me. But manual "Upload to ..." option works perfect.

Comment: Did you do step #4? For some strange for me reason lots of people simply missing or ignoring this step completely. Automatic deployment works with default server only -- and it has to be marked as Default even if it's only one configured for this project. If all good here ... then try restarting IDE. No other ideas for now.

Comment: As for 1 hour long video -- there are 3 links just above it -- no need to watch if you can read only what you need.

Comment: Actually this was set as default automatically. (FYI, I am using Mac, which may differ options). I just checked again, it shows an option "Stop Using As Default". Restart IDE, already tried.

Comment: I got the issue, I was actually saving with Cmd + S (which was the way of saving in NetBeans). But In PhpStorm, I see it uses Cntrl + S for saving. It's strange that, PhpStorm didn't customize it for Mac, where all save actions are done with Cmd + S. Anyways, that's a different issue, I will mark this question solved.

Comment: It most likely depends on your current Keymap -- try another one (in `Preferences`)

Comment: Many thanks, If found one keymap "Eclipse (Mac OS X)" which solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with multi deployement location you can declare a lot of "Deployement" PHPStorm configuration. (see : File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployement)

declare 2 differents deployement :

- One for your standard execution server web (with auto sync perhaps)
- Two for your Google Drive (manual sync)
- Three for another local or remote directory

Now when you finish to config all the deployement options you can :

- Sync auto with one deployement
- sync manually on other deployement with just click right on your local directory > click on "Upload To" (popup appear with your differents deployement config) > select your deployement

The Sync work with those technologies : FTP, SFTP, FTPS, local or mounted folder and in place.